# Download image from url Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to download a facebook profile photo using Parse Cloud Code and save it, however, it seems the redirect is not working properly - can someone give me some guidance? Thanks!

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: pictureURL,
    followRedirects: true
    }).then(function(httpResponse){
      var imgFile = new Parse.File(request.user.id+".jpg" , httpResponse.buffer);

      //the httpResponse does not resolve correctly

      return imgFile.save();

    }).then(function(){
        request.user.set(constants.kBPUserProfileImageKey, image);
        request.user.save();
        response.success("updated image");

    },function(error) {
          response.error("failed to save object");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think promise doesn't support for Parse.Cloud.httpRequest.
See the [api](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Cloud.html#.httpRequest)

Here is my code

```
// callback(savedParseFile, error)
   download: function (url, filename, callback) {

      Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
         url: url,
         followRedirects: true,
         success:function(httpResponse) {
            var parseFile = new Parse.File(filename , {base64: httpResponse.buffer.toString('base64', 0, httpResponse.buffer.length)});

            // parseFile.save().then(function() {
            //    callback(parseFile, null);
            // }, function(error) {
            //    console.error('Downloader fails to save parse file.');
            // });

            parseFile.save({
               success:function() {
                  callback(parseFile, null);
               }, error:function() {
                  callback(null, 'Downloader fails to save parse file.');
               }
            });
         },
         error:function(httpResponse) {
            callback(null, 'Downloader fails to download file.');
         }
      });
   }
```